# Como adaptar angular 10 a SEO

Tags: angular, seo

Estoy intentando hacer SEO friendly my web realizada con angular 10, pero no lo consigo al intentar utilizar angular universal. Sabéis cómo podría hacerlo? gracias

Answer (score 0):

Yo he utilizado el siguiente tutorial: [enlace](https://1938.com.es/app-seo-angular)

Así en grandes rasgos es:

```
 ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
 npm run build:ssr
 npm run serve:ssr
```

Esto último te funcionaria en una web algo simple. Realmente hay bastantes más a tener en cuenta por eso te recomiendo ver el  [tutorial](https://1938.com.es/app-seo-angular) (por ejemplo  qué pasa con window y localStorage que solamente puedes ejecutarlo en el navegador no en el lado del servidor  y su puesta en producción)

Un saludo.